# In react native firebase notifiation (FCM) ios image not visible

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, react-native

I want to receive notification with an image from FCM but the image is not display in the notification on iOS but work on Android.

here is my code.

AppDelegate.mm Code

```html
"#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>
#import "RNFBMessagingModule.h"

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
      //Foreground
      NSLog(@"APP_PUSH from foreground %@", userInfo);
     [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo
     fetchCompletionHandler:^void (UIBackgroundFetchResult result){}];
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification %@", userInfo);
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
  // Need to update
//  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
}

// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

// Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}"
```

"dependencies": {
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^16.4.6",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.6",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^16.4.6",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^16.7.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.4.6",
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"react": "17.0.2",
},

If you want more code please tell and which file code you want in ios.